# Is there a limit on project versions of Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment

I am automatically updating (and deploying) a web app in GAS, and the project version number is already over 270. I am worried there might exist an upper limit, but I cannot find any information regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE [2020-05-26]** The new IDE no longer allows version deletion (the new Apps Script API does not allow this either).

---

I have had projects where I generated well over a 1000 versions and I haven't hit a limit yet.

Also note that you can delete versions; so if you are concerned about hitting a limit you can always delete the older versions for your own peace of mind.