# Google Apps Script Active Deployment Limit

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, quota

Is there a limit to the number of simultaneous active deployments for a single project? I have been searching through Google's quota documentation and can find nothing about this.

Also, if there is a limit, is there any difference in the limit based on the type of deployment, e.g., web app, library, etc.?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but my experience suggests that for a single project you can have only one active deployment. The rest of them are either archived or libraries. You can have other active deployments in the same container or other containers under different projects. If this is not true, please inform me so that I can reconsider my belief and go beyond my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Apps Script Limitation:

To summarize this answer. Apps Script have a limitation of 50 for active deployments. There is no actual division on the type of deployment in terms of the General Limit but they have specific limits. You can read more on the reference provided. Please do note that things are bound to be changed and also the project version and deployment might be different in different contexts.

### Reference:

[Google Service Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

[Maximum Active Deployment for AppsScript](https://cloud.google.com/application-integration/docs/configure-apps-script-task#:%7E:text=Maximum%20active%20deployments%20for%20an%20AppsScript%3A%2050)

### Alternate Answer

I would also like to cover this post in case you have a different use case and might be referring to another context. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984449/is-there-a-limit-on-project-versions-of-google-apps-script) for possible duplicate questions.